# How to extract name of the day from the date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, dayofweek

I have some date and I need to get/extract only day from  those date. For example my output is
Day1: Wed Jun 10 2020 20:22:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Here I need to get only 'Wed' from the output.Here is the code below.

### javascript

```
function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
   dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
   return dateObj;
}

var day1 = new Date();
var day2 = addDays(new Date(), 1);
var day3 = addDays(new Date(), 2);
var day4 = addDays(new Date(), 3);
var day5 = addDays(new Date(), 4);

console.log(
    'Day1: ' + day1 +
    '\nDay2: ' + day2 +
    '\nDay3: ' + day3 +
    '\nDay4: ' + day4 +
    '\nDay5: ' + day5 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Date.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to format your Dates (and get the Weekday)

```js
function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
   dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
   return dateObj;
}

var day1 = new Date();
var day2 = addDays(new Date(), 1);
var day3 = addDays(new Date(), 2);
var day4 = addDays(new Date(), 3);
var day5 = addDays(new Date(), 4);

let options = { weekday: 'short' };

console.log(
    'Day1: ' + day1.toLocaleString('en-US',options) +
    '\nDay2: ' + day2.toLocaleString('en-US',options) +
    '\nDay3: ' + day3.toLocaleString('en-US',options) +
    '\nDay4: ' + day4.toLocaleString('en-US',options) +
    '\nDay5: ' + day5.toLocaleString('en-US',options) 
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please help me how to use this in angular 6

Comment: Post a new question with your angular code that needs to use this and how it needs to be used

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution:

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sun";
    weekday[1] = "Mon";
    weekday[2] = "Tue";
    weekday[3] = "Wed";
    weekday[4] = "Thu";
    weekday[5] = "Fri";
    weekday[6] = "Sat";

    function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
       dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
       return dateObj;
    }

    var day1 = new Date();
    var day2 = addDays(new Date(), 1);
    var day3 = addDays(new Date(), 2);
    var day4 = addDays(new Date(), 3);
    var day5 = addDays(new Date(), 4);

    console.log(
        'Day1: ' + weekday[day1.getDay()] +
        '\nDay2: ' + weekday[day2.getDay()] +
        '\nDay3: ' + weekday[day3.getDay()] +
        '\nDay4: ' + weekday[day4.getDay()] +
        '\nDay5: ' + weekday[day5.getDay()]
    );
```